# Hhow to create a react element and apply a javascript method to it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is there a way to create a function such that I could apply a javascript method to the React element variable within a function.

```
getTextBoxWidth(){
  var myTextBox = <text>Words here</text>;
  return myTextBox.textLength.baseVal.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do that but not in exact way you want to do it. It is doable via `ref`s: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html ([Especially this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component))

But there are special conditions. `JSX.Element` (`<text></text>` in your case) needs to be mounted (which means rendered in one way or another). And you will not be able get results in synchronized manner.

```
class SomeParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      textWidth: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      textWidth: this.textRef.current.textLength.baseVal.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <div> Text width = {this.state.textWidth !== undefined ? this.state.textWidth : "unknown"}</div>

      <text ref={this.textRef}>Words here</text>
    </div>
  }
}
```